# Webpack + react + firebase auth fail

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack

I'm trying to auth on firebase. I made everythin from tutorial on "react-create-app" and it worked but when I made it on project with webpack it didn't work. When I try to login or register email and password are just added to web address. On "react-create-app" it do POST request.
I think that I have to configure webpack. Do you have any idea?

webpack.config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/App.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebPackPlugin({template: "./src/index.html"})]
};
```

Comment: The form fields are being appended to the URL?

Comment: Yes but fields shouldn't be appended to URL. I use code from this project https://github.com/satansdeer/react-firebase-auth. Without webpack it works fine.

Comment: Can you show me the form and `submit`?